Intermittent "URL_UNREACHABLE-UNREACHABLE_CONNECTION_RESET" errors from Cloud Scheduler calling Cloud Function
I have a Cloud Scheduler job that triggers through a post a Cloud Function every minute. Most requests succeed, but occasionally the Cloud Scheduler logs show:

URL_UNREACHABLE-UNREACHABLE_CONNECTION_RESET. Original HTTP response code number = 0

These errors occur randomly, regardless of load (even with no traffic), and they never actually reach the function’s code. A quick retry from the Scheduler immediately succeeds.
The environment is always up, so it doesn’t seem like the function is down. Has anyone experienced similar transient connection reset issues with Cloud Scheduler, and how did you address them?

Seems like your issue needs to be inspected at project level and in-depth analysis is required to check the route cause. I recommend you to contact Google Support
